# How do I kill entities at y=65?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Potions can survive at y=65

One potion was thrown into the void, but instead of being killed, it just lingered there.

Any ideas to kill it? I can't just run `/kill @e[type=!player,tag=test1]`

(yes, the tag of the entity is indeed `test1` )

Answer (score 1):

First, create a scorebaord called "y".

```
/scoreboard objectives add y dummy
```

Then, the following commands are:

```
/execute as @e[tag=test1,type=!player] store result score @s y run data get entity @s Pos[1]
/kill @e[scores={y=65}]
```

The first one will give the score to the Potions acording to their Y axis and the second one will kill every entity that has their y coordinate to 65. Note that it will only work in that specific hight.

If you wish to kill everything from 65 and above use:

```
/kill @e[scores={y=65..}]
```

Side note: The void is actually under the 0 Y axis and not above or in the 65. Not sure what you meant there.