# need help with /execute to test for a team at a specific y level

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im trying to make a minigame on a server, and im having trouble detecting if a player is at a specific y level, here is what i have.

```
/execute if entity @a[team=Bluesumo] positioned ~ 4 ~
```

Bluesumo is the team name that you automatically join when you choose that team. Im trying to get a comparator output from the command block and have been receiving nothing. Yes, i am in the bluesumo team. I am in 1.16.4

Comment: Your command is a Java Edition command. Please add the tag `minecraft-java-edition` to your question if you are playing on that edition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I kill entities at y=65?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359883/how-do-i-kill-entities-at-y-65)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, eventually found it out.

```
/execute as @e[tag=blueteam,type=minecraft:player] store result score @s y run data get entity @s Pos[1]
```

Repeating, always active

```
execute if entity @e[scores={y=4}]
```

Repeating, always active